# Is there a sense in which $\tilde{K}$ is an exact functor?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, functors, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I'm going through [Hatcher's K-Theory script](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) for the first time and noticed that following theorem looked quite like a statement of the form “this functor is exact”:

> If $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $A\subset X$ is a closed subspace, then the inclusion and quotient maps $A\stackrel{i}\to X \stackrel{q}\to X/A$ induce homomorphisms $\tilde K (X/A) \stackrel{q^\ast}\to \tilde K(X) \stackrel{i^\ast}\to \tilde K (A)$ for which the kernel of $i^*$ equals the image of $q^*$.

Here, $\tilde K(X)$ stands for the equivalence class of vector bundles over $X$ such that $E\sim F$ if and only if they are isomorphic after adding trivial bundles of potentially different dimension.

Together with the notion of a pullback of bundles, it is not hard to show that $\tilde K$ forms a contravariant functor from $\underline{\text{CompHaus}}$ to $\underline{\text{AbGrp}}$. But can we equip the first category (or some equivalent category) with an abelian structure so that we could say this functor is in fact *exact*?

Comment: The sense is that K-theory forms a cohomology theory: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+%28Eilenberg-Steenrod%29+cohomology

Comment: Abelianness is not really the point. Very abstractly the point is that cohomology theories send homotopy cofiber sequences to homotopy fiber sequences but it takes awhile to connect this up to more concrete stuff: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofiber+sequence